# How can I know the type of dc (Windows device context) with Windows API

Tags: winapi, gdi

I got a handle of dc (of the type HDC ) under Windows. Can I get the type of that  cd(memory dc, window dc ,printer etc.) with Windows APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in general not possible, and usually not necessary either. A device context is meant to **abstract** the underlying implementation.

Occasionally, however, it is helpful to know, where the contents of a device context are displayed, to adjust rendering, for example. Calling [GetDeviceCaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877.aspx) with *nIndex* set to `TECHNOLOGY` retrieves that information. This doesn't allow you to discern between all four [Device Context Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183560.aspx) plus their subtypes, though.

Comment: Both screen DCs and memory DCs return `DT_RASDISPLAY` so this may be inadequate for some purposes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[GetObjectType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobjecttype) called on the HDC will return different values, including `OBJ_DC` and `OBJ_MEMDC`.

This is useful to differentiate screen DCs from memory DCs.

When creating fonts for memory DCs to export bitmaps `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY` is probably what you want. When creating fonts for the screen `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY` may be preferred.